# Create multiple different apps with the same firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I want to create two different apps that access the same firebase project. So, is the approach the same for both apps? As in I get the configuration and initialize firebase, or is there more to it?

Both projects are being done in react native with expo if that matters.

Thank you!

Comment: yup, the approach is the same for both apps. you'll just have to use the same GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to do.  Just configure each app as you would normally using the settings shown in the console for that app.